# Dynamic Block in Terraform - No more than 1 "dynamic_criteria" blocks are allowed

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating alerts in Azure by using terraform and getting below error

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alertrule"{
  
for_each = var.triggermap 
  
    name = each.key
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    scopes              = [data.azurerm_function_app.funcapp.id]
    description = each.value


  dynamic "dynamic_criteria" {
    for_each = local.metric_name
    content {
    metric_namespace   = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    metric_name        = dynamic_criteria.value
    aggregation        = "Total"
    operator           = "GreaterThan"
    alert_sensitivity  = "Medium" 
    ignore_data_before = timestamp() 

    dimension {
      name     = "Instance"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["*"]
    }
  

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.ag.id
  }
  }

}
}
```

I am getting below error, I am trying to create multiple alerts in azure by creating multiple dynamic criteria but when I am adding dynamic block it is giving me below issue, Above is my main.tf and in locals I am using simple map and list. please help

```
│ Error: Too many dynamic_criteria blocks
│
│   on ../module/alert.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alertrule":
│   58:     content {
│
│ No more than 1 "dynamic_criteria" blocks are allowed
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on ../module/alert.tf line 73, in resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alertrule":
│   73:   action {
│
│ Blocks of type "action" are not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on ../module/alert.tf line 73, in resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alertrule":
│   73:   action {
│
│ Blocks of type "action" are not expected here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `action` in `dynamic_criteria` which is not supported, it should be outside of it. Also you can have **only one** `dynamic_criteria`, not multiple ones as you are trying to do. Please check [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert):

> **One** of either criteria, dynamic_criteria or application_insights_web_test_location_availability_criteria must be specified.